# Go: SQL Lite Package not Loading from Workspace

Tags: go, import, package

New Go programmer here -- apologies in advance for any misused terminology or convention breaking -- I'm still getting up to speed on the language.  I'm trying to use this [sql lite](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) package in my go programs, and *sometimes* my program will fail with the following error

```
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: cannot open file        
/usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.a: open   
/usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.a: no such 
file or directory
```

This happens when I try to run my program with `go run main.go`.  The `go-sqlite3.a` file exists in my workspace package, but go doesn't want to load it for for some reason.  This only seems to happen when I try importing the module from a — sub-package (? not sure if this is the right term).

If I do the following in a single `main.go` file

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
  _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"    
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println("Hello World from main()")
}
```

everything works fine.  However, if I add a package to my program so the file structure is laid out like this

```
main.go
test/test.go
```

and I include my package (in `main.go`) like this

```
import(
    "fmt"
    "./test"    
)

func main(){
    test.Test()
}
```

and my package (`test/test.go`) looks like this

```
package test

import(
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"    
)

func Test(){
    fmt.Println("Hello World from Test() in test/test.go")
}
```

then `go run main.go` fails with the above error message.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  Is it wrong to use a `./` in my import?  I've tried reading up on this online, but I've had trouble finding something that addresses the behavior I'm seeing and the reasons for it.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong to import via `./`. *never* use an import by relative path. Is your GOPATH set correctly? You shouldn't have any 3rd party packages in your GOROOT.

Comment: @JimB thank you for your helpful comment.  Yes, GOPATH is set correctly (points to my workspace) Is there information anywhere that documents what importing by a relative path does and why you wouldn't want to use it?    Are applications and packages just not stored in the same repository in go projects?  Or should I be using the full package name if my project has both a main package and what I (probably incorrectly) called sub packages

Comment: [Relative Import Paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths). The problem is that if you use a relative import path you can't build that package from within a workspace. All imports are relative to `$GOPATH/src`, so just use the full import path even for "sub packages".

Comment: A great way to start with go is to read this: https://golang.org/doc/code.html and then do this small tutorial: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1 Go is a small language and it's pretty well documented. Also read the articles in the go blog about slices and concurency. You can go from noob to expert in no time.